# adding height or padding to d3 bottom axis

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I trying to make a graph with d3 and Vue.js but I'm having trouble with my X axis, I cannot seem to add padding or height to it.

Here is my sample code:

```
this.graph.g
    .select('.axes-wrapper')
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis-x')
    .style('font-size', '15px')
    .attr('transform',`translate(0,${this.graph.height})`)
    .attr('x', this.graph.width / 2)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.graph.x).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d %b %y')))
    .selectAll('text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-45)')
    .attr('x', -20)
    .attr('y', 10);
```

Problem that I'm having is when I set font size to as 15px and rotate my text by 45deg it goes out of the graph, and because I have overflow:hidden on svg element it is not visible. But I cannot set overflow to visible because it will cause me some other problem, so is there any way I can set height or add bottom padding to my X axis ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust margin here:-

```
 var  margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 20 };
var svg = d3.select('#some-id').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 500 + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr('height', 500 + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```